# indexing is not error but index + index = error

Tags: java

```
package hello2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Today_java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner broken = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = broken.nextLine();
        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(charArray[0]);
        System.out.println(charArray[1]);
        System.out.println(charArray[2]);

        System.out.printf("%d",charArray[0] + charArray[1] + charArray[2]);
    }
}
```

run this code print 1, 2, 3 is ok but 1 + 2 + 3 is error

ex) input 123 >> 1 / 2 / 3  > 150

really i can't find error and syntax error

help me... :(

Comment: Hint: `char + char` is resolved by promoting both characters to `int`. So you've got 49 + 50 + 51, as those are the `char` values for '1', '2' and '3'. If you want to parse the whole string as an integer, use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Thank you for your delicate reply.

Answer (score 1):

When you print 3 chars and use the "+" operator, it doesn't work as a concatenation operator like for `String`, because every char has an ASCII value from the ASCII table:

[image]

So 1+2+3 works as 49+50+51 = 150.

to print the 3 chars, use

```
System.out.printf("%c%c%c", charArray[0] , charArray[1] , charArray[2]);
```

Where `%c` is to format a `char`.

Comment: @박상훈 Did it work for you? I mean did you find that it is the answer which you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, The table above tells me which input value I put in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with add operation on the char

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Today {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Scanner broken = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = broken.nextLine();
          char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

          System.out.println(charArray[0]);
          System.out.println(charArray[1]);
          System.out.println(charArray[2]);

          System.out.printf("%d",Character.getNumericValue(charArray[0]) + Character.getNumericValue(charArray[1]) + Character.getNumericValue(charArray[2]));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%d",Character.getNumericValue(charArray[0]) +Character.getNumericValue(charArray[1]) + Character.getNumericValue(charArray[2]));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.